# Accessing nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having some trouble accessing the properties in the nested object. I've tried:

```
<p>{this.state.post.user.firstName}</p>
<p>{this.state.post.comments[0].user.firstName}</p>
```

Both lines don't not work, only `<p>{this.state.post.date}</p>` works.

Component:

```
    state = {
        post: {}
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const { post_id } = this.props.match.params;
        const response = await axios.get(`/posts/${post_id}`);

        this.setState({
            post: response.data
        })
    }

    render() { return( ...... )}
```

Here's an example of my json:

```
{ 
 "date": "2018", 
 "user": { "firstName": "Some Name" }, 
 "comments": [
   {
    "body": "here's my comment."
    "user": {
      "firstName": "Some Name", 
      "lastName": "Some Lastname"
     } 
   }, 
   {......}
 ]
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Comment: Could you show how you initialize the state? It might be that you are setting the state as the JSON string, and need to parse it first with `JSON.parse`.

Comment: When you're rendering, can you console.log or breakpoint into your state to check that it equals what you expect it to equal? Also Steve's answer is on point.

Comment: The it will work as-is--make sure you're operating on the data you think you are. (Assuming you have an actual object there, and not a string.)

Comment: Could you please show the error message?

Comment: You need to show the exact value of the `data` property. Are you handling the render for before the async request returns? Before it returns there's no data; this condition must be handled.

Comment: The errors suggest you are not: the component will do its initial render *before* `axios.get` returns and the data is put into state. You must handle the pre-Ajax rendering.

Comment: Hi Dave!!! I handled the pre-Ajax rendering and it's working now! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely getting these errors because you are not taking into consideration that `post` is initially an empty object, which will cause `this.state.post.user.firstName` and `this.state.post.comments[0]` to throw an error.

You could do this instead:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    post: null
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { post_id } = this.props.match.params;
    const response = await axios.get(`/posts/${post_id}`);

    this.setState({
      post: response.data
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { post } = this.state;

    return post ? (
      <div>
        <p>{post.user.firstName}</p>
        <p>{post.comments[0].user.firstName}</p>
        <p>{post.date}</p>
      </div>
    ) : null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for writing the whole thing out Tholle, your solution is cleaner than the one I implemented when Dave made the suggestion to the solution : )

Comment: @Tina Great! No problem.